# How do I use RpcRaiseException() for good error handling?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, error-handling, rpc

There's `RpcRaiseException()` function in MS RPC runtime to indicate errors that occur during an RPC call either on the server side or in a pipe callback on the client side. The RPC_STATUS passed into `RpcRaiseError()` is propagated to the site of the RPC call.

The problem is how do I choose the RPC_STATUS value?

Say in a pipe `pull()` callback I read data from `IStream*` and feed that data into the pipe. Now `IStream::Read()` returns an `HRESULT` indicating an error and I need to call `RpcRaiseException()` to interrupt the call.

What value do I pass?

Comment: What's wrong with just passing the HRESULT you got?  Sure beats RPC_E_SERVERFAULT.

Comment: Only one thing - I'm not sure it will produce a meaningful message on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an API which can fail, why not have the API return the failure code as the return value for the API?

If you DO want to use RpcRaiseException, the exception will be propogated as an exception to the client side so the exception code will show up as the RpcExceptionCode in the RpcExcept handler on the client side.

Comment: Do you mean I simply pass the HRESULT value into RpcRaiseError(). Otherwise I have no ways to indicate that something went wrong in the pipe callback.

Comment: No, you define your API as returning a HRESULT.  Then you simply return the error code from the server.

Comment: sharptooth: Note that I edited my answer for clarity and to correct an incorrect assumption.

Comment: I see. But I just can't do anything like that in a callback without inventing a huuuge wheel.

Comment: sharptooth - what happens when you just raise the Win32 error code as an exception?  The RPC server performing the callback *should* have wrapped the callback with an RpcTryExcept/RpcExcept handler to protect against transient RPC failures.